# creating a file (testfile.txt) in python 3 Jupyter note Book 6.0.3 in windows 7

Tags: python

How Can I create a file (testfile.txt) in python 3 Jupyter note Book 6.0.3 in windows 7? I'm working through Anaconda

```
 file1 = open("testfile.txt", "r")
```

Error

```
FileNotFoundError Traceback (most recent call last) FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2]
```

Thanks

Comment: You're trying to read a file. You should write it instead: `file1 = open("testfile.txt", "w")`

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to create a file use this

```
file1 = open("testfile.txt", "w")
```

the modes that are available are

1. 'r' This is the default mode. It Opens file for reading.
2. 'w' This Mode Opens file for writing. If file does not exist, it
   creates a
       new    file.If file exists it truncates the file.
3. 'x' Creates a new
       file. If    file already exists, the operation fails.
4. 'a' Open file
       in append    mode. If file does not exist, it creates a new file.
5. 't' This is the    default mode. It opens in text mode.
6. 'b' This
       opens in binary mode.
7. '+' This will open a file for reading and
       writing (updating)